# Draw lines between points, each moving in random direction

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, lines, points

I'm working on a Java Game using LWJGL. I made a particle system and would like to obtain same result as found on this website: http://play.cubedpixels.de

This is what I got so far:

[image: Picture]

I tried my best and the problem is it's stopping and they are only moving in one direction. Also the lines are not like on this website. On the website it's smoother and better. They are using OpenGL too.

How to solve these problems and make my implementation better, more like it is one the website?

The code below shows two classes: ParticleGalaxy and Particle. Latter one is inner class of the former, but for clarity I've split them into separate snippets.

**ParticleGalaxy**:

```
public class ParticleGalaxy
{
    private int count;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int mousex;
    private int mousey;
    public ArrayList<Particle> particles = new ArrayList();
    private Random random = new Random();
    private TimerUtil timer = new TimerUtil();
    int state = 0;
    int a = 255;
    int r = 255;
    int g = 0;
    int b = 0;

    public ParticleGalaxy(int count, int width, int height)
    {
        this.count = count;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            this.particles.add(
                new Particle(this.random.nextInt(width),
                this.random.nextInt(height)));
        }
    }

    public void drawParticles(int mousex, int mousey)
    {
        this.mousex = mousex;
        this.mousey = mousey;

        for(Particle p : this.particles)
        {
            if(p.reset)
            {
                p.resetPosSize();
                p.reset = false;
            }

            int x = Math.abs(p.getX() - mousex);

            int y = Math.abs(p.getY() - mousey);

            if((x < 40 && x > -40) && (y<35 && y>-40))
            {
                p.setConnect(true);
            }
            else
            {
                p.setConnect(false);
            }

            p.draw();
        }
    }
}
```

**Particle**:

```
public class Particle
{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int k;

    private int movey;
    private int movex;

    private int starty;
    private int startx;


    private int locationy;
    private int locationx;
    private float size;
    private boolean reset;
    private boolean connect;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private TimerUtil timer = new TimerUtil();

    private boolean moving = false;
    private boolean start = false;

    public Particle(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.startx = x;
        this.starty = y;
        this.size = genRandom(0.57F, 0.71F);
    }

    public void setConnect(boolean bool)
    {
        connect = bool;
    }

    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY()
    {
        return y;
    }

    private void drawLine(int xto, int yto, int xfrom, int yfrom)
    {
        GL11.glLineWidth(1.2f);
        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_LINE_STRIP);
        GL11.glVertex2d(xto, yto);
        GL11.glVertex2d(xfrom, yfrom);
        GL11.glEnd();
    }

    public void draw()
    {
        if(!start)
        {
            start = true;
            movex = height - random.nextInt(height);
            movey = width - random.nextInt(width);
            move(startx, starty, movex, movey);
        }

        float speed = 1;
        float elapsed = 0.01f;

        // On starting movement
        float distance = (float)Math.sqrt(Math.pow(movex - startx, 2) +
                                          Math.pow(movey - starty, 2));
        float directionX = (movex - startx) / distance;
        float directionY = (movey - starty) / distance;

        if(moving == true)
        {
            x += directionX * speed * elapsed;
            y += directionY * speed * elapsed;

            if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - startx, 2) + Math.pow(y - starty, 2)) >= distance)
            {
                x = (int)movex;
                y = (int)movey;
                resetPosSize();
                this.reset = true;
                moving = false;
            }
        }

        this.k += 1;

        int xx = 0;
        int yy = 0;

        this.locationx = this.x + xx;
        this.locationy = this.y + yy;

        if(locationx < 0 || locationy < 0)
            this.reset = true;

        if(locationx > width || locationy > height)
            this.reset = true;

        GuiUtils.drawCircle(this.x + xx, this.y + yy, this.size, -1);

        if(connect)
        {
            for(Particle p : particles)
            {
                if(p.connect)
                    drawLine(locationx, locationy, p.locationx, p.locationy);
            }
        }
    }

    public void move(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
    {
        x = (int)startX;
        y = (int)startY;
        moving = true;
    }

    public void resetPosSize()
    {
        this.x = this.random.nextInt(ParticleGalaxy.this.width);
        this.y = this.random.nextInt(ParticleGalaxy.this.height);
        startx = x;
        starty = y;
        movex = height - random.nextInt(height);
        movey = width - random.nextInt(width);
        move(startx, starty, movex, movey);
    }

    public float genRandom(float min, float max)
    {
        return (float)(min + Math.random() * (max - min + 1.0F));
    }
}
```

Comment: So do you want to know how to render the lines efficiently or do you want to know how to calculate the lines?

Comment: They need to be smoother and somehow not pixilated

Comment: +Dynamitos I need a random waypoint generator of the circles